# How to derive the Indirect Utility Function and Marshallian Demand from Homothetic Preferences

Tags: utility, demand

I need to prove the following relationships:

1 - If preferences are homothetic, then the indirect utility function can be written as
$v(p, w) = v(p) · w$.

2 - If preferences are homothetic, then the Marshallian demand functions take the form
$x_i(p, w) = x_i(p) · w$, i.e., they are linear functions of income.

I know that I can use the Roy's Identity and the connections below:
$$ e(p,v(p,w))=w$$ $$v(p,e(p,u))=u,$$
but I can't organize this answer.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you apply Roy's identity to the utility function of point 1 ? (it is embarassing btw to use the same notation $v$ for denoting two different functions)

Comment: If I use a Roy's Identity in point 1, I derive the Marshallian demand from item 2. I am wondering how to prove that point 1 is true. (Thanks for the tip! It was just to indicate a function of p, but I can use another notation.)

Comment: This may help: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/8519/how-to-show-that-a-homothetic-utility-function-has-demand-functions-which-are-li?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, @Bertrand!